# Connecting to site in java using URLConnection throwing 403 Forbidden (User-Agent doesn't fix it)

Tags: java, wamp

I'm using a wamp server on localhost and have a small Java software that should make a request to my website (written in PHP) once a week to send out a weekly mail. But the request throws an IOException saying that a 403 was returned. Here is the Exception:

```
Sending first mail at 11-8-2014 8:00.
Sending mail.
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost/mailUnmanaged
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.zetup.resurs.weeklyMail.SendWeeklyMail$Task.run(SendWeeklyMail.java:89)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After some googling i found that setting the User-Agent in the request would solve it. It didn't for me.

Here is the part where I'm sending the request:

```
URL url;    
try {
    url = new URL("http://localhost/mailUnmanaged");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
try {
    System.out.println("Sending mail.");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", url.getHost()); // I've tried without this
    conn.connect();
    System.out.println(conn.getContent().toString());
    lastTime.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I copy the url and paste it to my browser it works fine.

**EDIT:**
I have a pretty extensive .htaccess, maybe that could cause problems?

**EDIT: MORE TESTS**
So, I checked all the headers Chrome sent and set all the headers in my code and it still returns 403. This is starting to get wierd.

Comment: If you go to the URL with your browser it works?

Comment: If you replace `localhost` by say `google.com` what is the output?

Comment: @mtk FileNotFoundException

Comment: @SiXOS, i believe you actually tried this. If not then please retry with this.. `new URL("https://www.google.com");`. If you did, ignore, there seems to be some other issue

Comment: @mtk I had not. It did work fine though, so you are correct, it's a diffrent problem.

Comment: Well, since it's a server-side error, what does the server log say?

Comment: could it be that you need to provide a username and password (and that maybe your browser has these cached for you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. As I'm using Windows 8 the IP used to connect to my site is ::1 (The IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1). In my httpd.conf I only allowed requests from IP ::1. I had to add 127.0.0.1 to the allowed IP:s. My new httpd.conf has:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Directory>
```